# Magento site wider on chrome mobile browser than on chrome desktop browser -due to floating right div?- genius needed

Tags: html, css, magento

I have a site which has a tiny sidebar with the social icons on the right side of the page.

On the desktop version these social icons are placed on the right side in Chrome as should be: live version http:// ont.999games.nl/ the-unusual-suspects.html

[chrome desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QA5r.jpg)

On the mobile browser these social icons are not visible unless you slide the page to the left:

[chrome mobile browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvqWj.jpg)

I have tried a range of css and metatag tricks but none have resulted in a page exactly as wide as the browser with the social icons visible on the right side.
set my container DIVs to position:relative, then set content DIVs to position:fixed. Tried adding metatag viewport, and versions thereof. All didn't work.

Is there a magician who does know why this is happening and more importantly how to fix it?

Comment: You need to share some of your code for us to be able to help

Comment: the link which you have provided works fine in my mobile chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the issue in either chrome desktop reduced to mobile width, or on mobile. It's looking ok to me on both.